# Javac bootclasspath option

Tags: javac

I try to add -bootclasspath option when compiling java source like this:

```
javac -classpath lib/* -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -bootclasspath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/*.jar Hello.java
```

I am getting the following error when compiling:

```
javac: invalid flag: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/dt.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

How should I add the bootclasspath parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this -bootclasspath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar instad of /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/*.jar and it worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

The shell expands /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/*.jar to the list of jars, so effectively javac is called like that:

```
javac ... -bootclasspath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/rt.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/dt.jar ... Hello.java
```

You can avoid that by putting the path between single quotes:

```
javac ... -bootclasspath '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/*.jar' ... Hello.java
```

Comment: You cannot use "*.jar" in classpath references passed to javac or java executables. If you want to include multiple JAR files, they need to be separated by ":" (colon) on Unix/Linux and ";" (semicolon) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

java -bootclasspath $(set -- /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/*.jar ; IFS=:; echo "$*")

Be running bash when you try it, the bourne again shell is the bee's knees.